# How to set an Id property using linq based on the id set in a preceding object in EF DbInitializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a DbInitializer class with a seed method in it that is seeding some initial data into my db and I'm now adding additional data to the seeding and this data creates the relation table between a dog and a color. I'm trying to do something as follows which the compiler complaining about.

```
      var breeds = new List<Breeds>()
        {
            new Breeds()
            {
                BreedId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Belgian Malinois",
                AvgMinHeight = 22,
                AvgMaxHeight = 26,
                AvgMinWeight = 40,
                AvgMaxWeight = 80

            },
            new Breeds()
            {
                BreedId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Dutch Shepherd",
                AvgMinHeight = 21,
                AvgMaxHeight = 25,
                AvgMinWeight = 42,
                AvgMaxWeight = 75
            }
        }; //end

        if (!_context.Breeds.Any())
        {
            _context.Breeds.AddRange(breeds);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

       //Breed Color Relational Data Seeding
       if (!_context.BreedColors.Any())
        {
            var breedColors = new List<BreedColors>()
            {
                new BreedColors()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    BreedId = breeds.Where(x=>x.Name=="Dutch Shepherd").Single();
                    //ColorId = 
                }
            };

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. The following syntax works when trying to assign the id  from a Id property of a related object based.

```
        var breedColors = new List<BreedColors>()
        {
            new BreedColors()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                BreedId = breeds.Where(x=> x.Name=="Dutch Shepherd").Select(x=> x.BreedId).Single(),
                ColorId = colors.Where(b=>b.Name == "Wolfgray & Black").Select(a => a.Id).Single()
            }
        };
```